# Kubernetes: Can't delete PersistentVolumeClaim (pvc)

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I created the following persistent volume by calling

`kubectl create -f nameOfTheFileContainingTheFollowingContent.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-monitoring-static-content
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/some/path"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-monitoring-static-content-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
```

After this I tried to delete the pvc. But this command stuck.
when calling `kubectl describe pvc pv-monitoring-static-content-claim` I get the following result

```
Name:          pv-monitoring-static-content-claim
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Terminating (lasts 5m)
Volume:        pv-monitoring-static-content
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed=yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller=yes
Finalizers:    [foregroundDeletion]
Capacity:      100Mi
Access Modes:  RWO
Events:        <none>
```

And for `kubectl describe pv pv-monitoring-static-content`

```
Name:            pv-monitoring-static-content
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller=yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection foregroundDeletion]
StorageClass:
Status:          Terminating (lasts 16m)
Claim:           default/pv-monitoring-static-content-claim
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
Capacity:        100Mi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /some/path
    HostPathType:
Events:            <none>
```

There is no pod running that uses the persistent volume. Could anybody give me a hint why the pvc and the pv are not deleted?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

This happens when persistent volume is protected. You should be able to cross verify this:

Command:

`kubectl describe pvc PVC_NAME | grep Finalizers`

Output:

`Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]`

You can fix this by setting finalizers to null using `kubectl patch`:

```
kubectl patch pvc PVC_NAME -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers": []}}' --type=merge
```

Ref; [Storage Object in Use Protection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#storage-object-in-use-protection)

Comment: that solution works best than edit solution accross corporate firewalls

Comment: @codersofthedark it does not explain the cause. Of course it is protected. That's what I already mentioned in my question. But the volume wasn't used by any Pod => protection shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: I am having this issue and when I tried the command above to patch the pvc, kept getting the error `unable to parse "'{metadata:{finalizers:": yaml: found unexpected end of stream`

Comment: for my case, the PVCs are protected cuz I only deleted StatefulSet, not the underlying pods, so the PVCs are still being used by Pods, that's why it is in TERMINATING phase

Comment: I'm on GKE and something seems to be setting the finalizer back immediately. :/

Comment: @weberc2 I have the same issue, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 24):

I'm not sure why this happened, but after deleting the finalizers of the pv and the pvc via the kubernetes dashboard, both were deleted.
This happened again after repeating the steps I described in my question.
Seems like a bug.

Comment: I had a similar problem: PVC didn't want to die and because of that the project was in "Terminating" state forever. I did `oc edit pvc/protected-pvc -n myproject` and deleted those two lines about finalizers. Both PVC and the projects were gone immediately.
I agree it's probably a bug because it should not behave that way. I didn't have any pods running in that project, just that PVC.

Comment: I just came across this same problem, with this being the solution for me too...delete the constraints.  This isn't a "thank you" comment.  Rather, I'm adding this because it's 7+ months later and this problem still seems to exist in the wild, and thought new readers might benefit in knowing that.  I'm running the latest 'minikube' (installed and built just a few days ago) behind an up to date "Docker for Mac".

Comment: ...I'm following an online tutorial.  I don't know if this is related to this bug, but the behavior I get is different than the instructor's.  He creates a new PVC and its state is initially "Pending".  Only when he manually creates a PV does the state of the PVC become "bound".  In my case, it seems that creating the PVC using the same command he does immediately creates a PV to use the PVC allocated storage.  Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: As answer is not complete in my opinion (not explaining steps of a solution for laics) - You can remove Finalizers in dashboard in YAML of particular PV. Additionally you can do that in terminal by:
`kubectl patch pvc NAME -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'`,
`kubectl patch pod NAME -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'`. Source https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69697#issuecomment-489876217

Comment: Already mentioned in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56182934/2576531

Answer (score 24):

You can get rid of editing your pvc! Remove pvc protection.

1. kubectl edit pvc YOUR_PVC -n NAME_SPACE
2. Manually edit and put # before this line 
   [image]
3. All pv and pvc will be deleted

Comment: This comment has helped me with deleting a volume that was stuck in Terminating state. thanks.

Answer (score 15):

The PV is protected. Delete the PV before deleting the PVC. Also, delete any pods/ deployments which are claiming any of the referenced PVCs. For further information do check out [Storage Object in Use Protection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#storage-object-in-use-protection)

Comment: I tried to delete both. The pv and the pvc. As you can see in the describe output both are in terminating state

Comment: What platform are you using? Have you tried to delete using `kubectl create -f nameOfTheFileContainingTheFollowingContent.yaml` ?

Answer (score 12):

For me pv was in retain state, hence doing the above steps did not work.

1st we need to change policy state as below :

```
kubectl patch pv PV_NAME -p '{"spec":{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Delete"}}'
```

Then delete pvc as below.

```
kubectl get pvc

kubectl delete pvc PVC_NAME
```

finally, delete pv with

```
kubectl delete pv PV_NAME
```

Answer (score 7):

Just met this issue hours ago.

I deleted deployments that used this references and the PV/PVCs are automatically terminated.

Comment: Thank you! this works for me

Answer (score 6):

If PV still exists it may be because it has ReclaimPolicy set to Retain in which case it won't be deleted even if PVC is gone. From the docs:

> PersistentVolumes can have various reclaim policies, including
>   “Retain”, “Recycle”, and “Delete”. For dynamically provisioned
>   PersistentVolumes, the default reclaim policy is “Delete”. This means
>   that a dynamically provisioned volume is automatically deleted when a
>   user deletes the corresponding PersistentVolumeClaim. This automatic
>   behavior might be inappropriate if the volume contains precious data.
>   In that case, it is more appropriate to use the “Retain” policy. With
>   the “Retain” policy, if a user deletes a PersistentVolumeClaim, the
>   corresponding PersistentVolume is not be deleted. Instead, it is moved
>   to the Released phase, where all of its data can be manually recovered

Comment: `Recycle` is deprecated now

Answer (score 6):

In my case, as long as I delete the pod associated to both `pv` and `pvc`, the `pv` and `pvc` in terminating status are gone

Comment: "There is no pod running that uses the persistent volume"

Comment: I met this issue again today. 2 PVs, without Pod and PVC associated, turned into ```terminating``` state forever, when being deleted.

To fix it, I ran ```kubectl patch pv local-pv-324352d9 -n ops -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers": []}}' --type=merge```

Then the PV is gone. Thanks @Xiak hint

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl get pvc pvc_name -o yaml > pvcfile.yaml
```

Then open pvcfile.yaml and delete the finalizers line, save and apply :

```
kubectl apply -f pvcfile.yaml
```

Comment: Instead of two commands, it can be done as 'kubectl edit pvc pvc_name', then remove the section and save.

BTW, as per the original question, the author removed the PVC - but that operation failed due to other reasons as specified in the above answers.

Answer (score 0):

in my case a pvc was not deleted because missing namespace (I deleted the namespace before deleting all resources/pvc) 
solution : create namespace with the same name as it was before and then I was able to remove the `finalizers` and finally pvc

Answer (score 0):

In case you have already deleted PV and trying to delete PVC

Check if the volume is attached by this command

kubectl get volumeattachment

Deleting the PVC :-

First you have to delete pvc pne by one using this command

kubectl delete pvc <pvc_name> --grace-period=0 --force

Or you can delete all PVC's using

kubectl delete pvc --all

Now you can see the status of PVC as terminating by using

kubectl get pvc

and then you have to apply this delete using

kubectl patch pvc {PVC_NAME} -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the other answers about the finalizer...

I could free up the resources only after deleting the Deployment. After that, the Terminating resources got released.

---

Delete all the resources listed by:

```
kubectl get all -n YOURNAMESPACE
```

Use `kubectl delete -n YOURNAMESPACE <resource> <id>` or (if you copy paste from the above output) `kubectl delete -n YOURNAMESPACE <resource>/<id>`, for each resource that you see listed there.

You can also do it at once

```
kubectl delete -n YOURNAMESPACE <resource>/<id1>  <resource>/<id2>  <resource2>/<id3>  <resource2>/<id4>  <resource3>/<id5>
```

Probably you tried to remove resources but they are getting recreated because of the `deployment` or `replicaset` resource, preventing the namespace from freeing up depending resources and from being cleaned up.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour for protected volumes. When the deployment still uses the volume it cant be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I had pods referencing the PVC. The pods were job executions which had completed. I deleted the completed pods and the delete command finished on it's own.