# delete improperly removed PersistentVolume in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, storage-class-specifier

It seems like, While deleting the pv,pvc, I have messed up. I can delete the pvc without issues but I can not delete the pv that pv-protection in it. while deleting pv,pvc earlier, I have pressed CTRL+C since it was taking time to delete it and also deleted the storageclass before deleting the pvc. I don't remember the storage class that was used for creating the pvc.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358856/kubernetes-cant-delete-persistentvolumeclaim-pvc), it says, updating the pvc protection to null will help remove the pvc. But I had to delete the pv which has pv-protection. The below is the describe output of pv.

```
~/github/vault-operator# kubectl describe pv pv-hostpath
Name:            pv-hostpath
Labels:          type=local
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    manual
Status:          Terminating (lasts <invalid>)
Claim:           poc-namespace/pvc-hostpath
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
Capacity:        1Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:         
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /kube
    HostPathType:  
Events:            <none>

~/github/vault-operator# kubectl get pv,pvc
NAME                           CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS        CLAIM                            STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/pv-hostpath   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Terminating   poc-namespace/pvc-hostpath   manual                  11d
```

question is, how can i delete the pv that is not deleted properly and what could be my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, you have a PVC (poc-namespace/pvc-hostpath) that is preventing your PV from being deleted. Delte the PVC, and you can delete the PV.

Generally speaking, the `Reclaim Policy` of a PVC is `delete`, by default, so when you delete a PVC, it automatically deletes the PV bound to it.

Your `storageClass` probably was [this](https://github.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner) one (or similar), from rancher. It is a `hostPath` based one, meaning it maps your container volume to the host machine.

Comment: I missed to recognize this pvc bcoz it was in different namespace. good catch.