# MongoDB not persistent in kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to configure mongodb deployment inside k8s world. 
My mongo deployment file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: panel-admin-mongo-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: panel-admin-mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: panel-admin-mongo
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: panel-admin-mongo-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: database-persistent-volume-claim
      containers:
        - name: panel-admin-mongo
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: panel-admin-mongo-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
```

Mongo service file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: panel-admin-mongo-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: panel-admin-mongo
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

And my persistent volume claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: database-persistent-volume-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

When I'm entering the mongodb container using:
`kubectl exec -it panel-admin-mongo-deployment-6dcfc5b8c7-mk8d5 sh`
and I'm saving some users email and password inside the collection (f.ex. users) everything works fine. But when I shot down the pod and container inside of it, boot up again, the data is gone. Shouldn't be independent of life-cycle of pod? And if yes what am I missing?

Comment: I've reproduced your yaml files on Minikube and GKE and it works as expected. Can you add information about how to reproduce this problem? How are you injecting this data to database?

Comment: So as I understand you are able to delete mongo deployment file and boot it up again and the data will be there? I'm injecting the data entering the pod with `kubectl exec -it [pod-name] sh`, then `mongo`, then `use [mydbname]` and f.ex. `db.users.save({ email: "test@test.com" })`

Comment: Yes, for me it hust works fine. I'm deploying your `PersistentVolumeClaim`, than your `Deployment`. I'm not changing anything, copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a k8s expert, but your problems is that you are not using Kubernetes statfulsets, have a look here
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/

AFAIK, for any persistent deployment you need to make your pods using statefulsets.

Comment: Not required if using PVC.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you pod success usage PVC:

```
kubectl describe po/${POD_NAME}
```

and check `Volumes` section:

```
Volumes:
  prometheus-operator-db:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  prometheus-operator-db-0
    ReadOnly:   false
```

If you success usage `PVC`, need check [reclaim-policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/#changing-the-reclaim-policy-of-a-persistentvolume) for you `PV`, this value should be `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Retain"`.

Comment: When I'm checking reclaim-policy it show `delete` with status of `terminating` and it stucked like this. When I want to delete pvc it stucks as well

Comment: try deleting it using flags `--force --grace-period=0`

Comment: I've finally deleted it using the first answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358856/kubernetes-cant-delete-persistentvolumeclaim-pvc

Comment: I've change reclaim policy to `retain` with ```kubectl patch pv <your-pv-name> -p '{"spec":{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Retain"}}'``` and indeed not it is `retain` when inspecting `pv`. But again the same story happens: I save some data in db, then I delete mongo deployment and mongo pod, I boot up again mongo deployment and when I enter into the db inside the pod I can't see data there. When I delete mu mongo deployment I can see that `pv` exists and it has indeed `retain policy`

Comment: Followed this before reading the docs. Retain does not make data persist. It just retains the volume for later manual recovery of data. Kubernetes will still create a new PVC with default Delete policy and bind it to the mongo service. It will set status to Release on the original one but keep it around instead of deleting it.