# Problem : Delete PVC (Persistent Volume Claim) Kubernetes Status Terminating

Tags: kubernetes, storage, cluster-computing, kubernetes-pvc

Basically, I have a problem deleting my `spoc-volume-spoc-ihm-kube-test` PVC I tried with:

```
kubectl delete -f file.yml
kubectl delete PVC
```

but I get every time the same Terminating Status. Also, when I delete the PVC the console is stuck in the deleting process.

Capacity: 10Gi
Storage Class: rook-cephfs
Access Modes: RWX

Here is the status in my terminal:

> kubectl  get pvc
> NAME                                    STATUS        VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS      AGE
> spoc-volume-spoc-ihm-kube-test          Terminating   pvc-*-*  10Gi       RWX            rook-cephfs       3d19h

Thank You for your answers,
Stack Community :)

Comment: did you have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358856/kubernetes-cant-delete-persistentvolumeclaim-pvc?rq=1 ?

Comment: Can you describe the pvc? `kubectl describe pvc spoc-volume-spoc-ihm-kube-test` ?

Comment: Hello Thank you for the correction, yes I saw that response too, I fixed the problem with my colleague, the problem was simple; as long as you keep other pods, which depends on that pvc at a running state, the pvc will never be deleted. That's a also, I think one of the principle of Kubernetes, as long as the pod communicate with the pvc, the pvc can not be deleted,.

Comment: Thank's a lot @KamolHasan `kubectl describe pvc spoc-volume-spoc-ihm-kube-test` is a good way to describe the pod, I will use it next time. My app works perfectly in the cluster !

Answer (score 14):

You need to first check if the volume is attached to a resource using `kubectl get volume attachment`. If your volume is in the list, it means you have a resource i.e a pod or deployment that is attached to that volume. The reason why its not terminating is because the PVC and PV metadata `finalizers` are set to `kubernetes.io/pv-protection`.

#### Solution 1:

Delete the resources that are attached/using the volume i.e pods, deployments or statefulsets etc. After you delete the stuck PV and PVC will terminate.

#### Solution 2

If you are not sure where the volume is attached, you can delete/patch the PV and PVC metadata `finalizers` to null as follows:

a) Edit the PV and PVC and delete or set to null the `finalizers` in the metadata

```
kubectl edit pv {PV_NAME}
kubectl edit pvc {PVC_NAME}
```

b) Simply patch the PV and PVC as shown below:

```
kubectl patch pvc {PV_NAME} -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
kubectl patch pvc {PVC_NAME} -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the problem by deleting the pods depending on that pvc

The `status: TERMINATING` disappeared

Answer (score 0):

This issue due to still pod referring deleted claim.

If you are using OCP, Go to **Workload -> DeploymentConfig** and edit the deployment configuration.

Remove your old deleted claim from the yaml configuration under **VolumeMounts** and **Volumes** section.

This fix is resolved my issue. I hope this will help.